# Return variable value of JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

So guys, I have a JavaScript function that should return an Array with values. Here is the function:

```js
let finalInput;
let input;
function getCorrectInput (input, finalInput) {
  input = prompt("Type the client type followed by" +
  "semicollon and the dates separated by comma"+
  "(Following the example: Reward: 31Dez2019(weekday), 01Jan2020(weekday)):");

  while (input === undefined || input === null || input === '') {
    input = prompt("Type the client type followed by" +
    "semicollon and the dates separated by comma"+
    "(Following the example: Reward: 31Dez2019(weekday), 01Jan2020(weekday)):");
  } 

  if (input) 
    return 

    finalInput = input.split(',');
  
  return finalInput
}

getCorrectInput()
```

Basically, the function verifies if the field contains something (if the user typed) and returns the content inside the input. So the output of the function should be something like that:

```
finalInput = ["Reward", "date1", "date2"]
```

I need to access the finalInput at position [0], and pass it to a variable, like that:

```
const clientType = finalInput[0]
```

But when I try to access the finalInput, it returns an error saying that it cannot read property 0 of undefined. So it means that the code is not returning the array with the values.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A `prompt` in a `while` loop is an awful choice; I'm tempted to remove it from the question entirely as you can't "Cancel" it. That said, `if (input) return`... this will exit the function if `input` is any truthy value.

Comment: I see `return` without semicolons, in a basic question. I wonder, do i have to read further? As a note, `return` followed by a newline parses as `return;`.

Comment: The condition `if (input)` is pointless, after your loop this condition is always `true` and `return` exits the function, returning `undefined`

Comment: `semicollon` might want to check your spelling

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 variables named `finalInput`.

- The one defined on line 1 which you don't touch until `finalInput[0]` (so it is undefined)
- The one defined as a function parameter on line 3

You return the second one with `return finalInput` but you never assign it anywhere (there is nothing before `getCorrectInput()`).

1. Remove the declaration of the second one, since you never pass it in as an argument
2. Define your local variables with `let` inside the function
3. Assign the return value somewhere

Such:

```
function getCorrectInput () {
    let finalInput;
    let input;

    // etc

    return finalInput;
}

let finalInput = getCorrectInput();
```

Also remove this:

> ```
>   if (input) 
>     return
> ```

As it exits the function early for no apparent reason.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning **before** the logic you need. So:

```
if (input) 
    return // CHANGE THIS
```

Change it to:

```
if (input) {
    return input.split(',');
}
```

Right now it just returns an `undefined` value because there is input. If you want a conditional to check if there is NOT a value, then you need to do `if (input === null || input === undefined) { // LOGIC }` to check if you didn't get input.

Answer (score 0):

You have there this:

```
 if (input) 
    return
```

so if `input` exists then you return undefined as you do not return anything and you never reach the part where you return the finalInput.

Comment: It probably was meant to be `if (!input)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is your check on the input variable, the expression is always true while there's a user entry, and it gives result to an unreachable statements,

So to solve this you need to change the check on the 'input' variable as follow :

- if( input == null )

And you are OK (y)

```js
let finalInput;
let input;
function getCorrectInput (input, finalInput) {
  input = prompt("Type the client type followed by" +
  "semicollon and the dates separated by comma"+
  "(Following the example: Reward: 31Dez2019(weekday), 01Jan2020(weekday)):");

  while (input === undefined || input === null || input === '') {
    input = prompt("Type the client type followed by" +
    "semicollon and the dates separated by comma"+
    "(Following the example: Reward: 31Dez2019(weekday), 01Jan2020(weekday)):");
  } 

  if (input == null ) 
    return 

    finalInput = input.split(',');
  
  return finalInput
}
//Just to log your result
var result = getCorrectInput()
console.log(result )
```